# WCF net.p2p:// - Can I connect using a different port than listening?

Tags: .net, wcf, p2p, net.p2p

I have the following code that starts a WCF P2P service:

```
private static readonly EndpointAddress EndpointAddress =
    new EndpointAddress("net.p2p://eigenein.Test.Wcf");
...
public void Start()
{
    NetPeerTcpBinding binding = new NetPeerTcpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
    ServiceEndpoint endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(
        ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IChat)),
        binding, 
        EndpointAddress);
    endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProtoEndpointBehavior());
    host = new Chat();
    channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IChatChannel>(
        new InstanceContext(host), endpoint);
    channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    channel.Open();
}
```

As I understand, WCF automatically determines the listening port and the port to connect to the other peer. But can I set up two specific different ports for each peer: the port to listen to and the specific port to connect to the other peer? Something like:

```
private static readonly EndpointAddress SourceEndpointAddress =
    new EndpointAddress("net.p2p://eigenein.Test.Wcf:808");
private static readonly EndpointAddress TargetEndpointAddress =
    new EndpointAddress("net.p2p://eigenein.Test.Wcf:909");
```

The thing I want to achieve: allow peers to connect through a static NAT port mappings. I'm not able to change these mappings.

Comment: I don't know how far you are with your development, but starting with .NET 4.5, NetPeerTcpBinding is deprecated. You might consider using another library for P2P.

Comment: @JulienLebosquain, could you provide a proof-link, please?

Comment: Sure, here you are: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netpeertcpbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @JulienLebosquain can you recommend some other library for p2p?